# How to redirect the referrer? The full domain, not only single address

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have the following redirecting script on my site:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer == "http://dontwantthisreferrer.com/") {
   document.location = "http://urltoredirect.com/";
 }
</script>
```

My question is: how to block a full domain of http://dontwantthisreferrer.com? Now i'm redirecting only from the main page, not from i.e. http://dontwantthisreferrer.com/post-1/ and i want to redirect from all the addresses of this domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `indexOf` method to check if your domain name exists in the referrer address.

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf("http://dontwantthisreferrer.com") == 0) {
    document.location = "http://urltoredirect.com/";
}
```

Otherwise you can use regular expressions to do the same but in a bit more flexible way.

```
if (/^http:\/\/(www.)?dontwantthisreferrer.com/.test(document.referrer)) {
    document.location = "http://urltoredirect.com/";
}
```

By the way, the good option is to use server-side solution for your task. For example, the same can be easily done not only with PHP, Python, Perl, etc but also with your web server config (e.g. with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)).

Comment: that's what i did, but unfortunately forgot the `www`. And one more thing, (sorry to say this :) it fails for https

Comment: I saw your `https` check but I haven't included it since there is nothing said about HTTPS support. And `www` is a typical issue.

Comment: that's why i've updated my answer...all right let the questioner choose the answer...btw hey questioner! where the heck are you?

Answer (score 0):

Use regex.

```
if (/^https?:\/\/(www.)?dontwantthisreferrer.com\//.test(document.referrer)) {
   document.location = "http://urltoredirect.com/";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First extract protocol and domain part:

```
var referrer = /^(https?:\/\/[^\/]*)/.exec(document.referrer)
if (referrer && referrer[1] == "http://dontwantthisreferrer.com") {
    ducument.location = "http://urltoredirect.com"
}
```

That way it is easy to test for array of domains if needed, like in the following example. Note, I changed the regex `/^https?:\/\/([^\/:]*)/`, to extract just the domain without protocol.

```
var forbidden_referrers = ["www.referrer1.com", "www.referrer2.com"]
var referrer = /^https?:\/\/([^\/:]*)/.exec(document.referrer)
referrer && for (i in forbidden_referrers) {
    forbidden_referres[i] == referrer[1] && document.location = "http://urltoredirect.com"
}
```